# Bound / asymptotic of series involving Moebius function

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

It is known that:

$$\Bigg| \Big(\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\Big)^{k)} \Bigg|= \Bigg  |\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} \log^k{n} \Bigg|$$

when $\Re(s) > 1$. Can you help find a bound or asymptotic ? No matter how sharp/trivial it is.  I am specially interested when $k \to \infty$.

Comment: Actually, we can consider $\Re(s)=\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: Does the exponent on the left mean power or derivative?

Comment: Also, on the right, should the $(-1)^k$ be $(-1)^n$?

Comment: @martycohen The exponent on the LHS should be kth  derivative, of the inverse of $\zeta(s)$. If I am not wrong, the $(-1)^k$ just grabs the sign change added by every increment in the derivative k.

Comment: The index of summation is $n$, not $k$, so $(-1)^k$ does not affect the absolute value.